# Sharepoint Designer, web part zone and table column

Tags: sharepoint, templates

I am learning to create a template in sharepoint 2007, using SPD 2007 from a site collection.
I've been using some of the template that comes with MS-sharepoint 2007 for my team.  But they found a site that they like the look and feel of it.  http://ic.buffalostate.edu.
How i am going to create a template like that, I do not do coding.  Please help...any advise would be very much appreciate.

Comment: Do you do web design? It is more an effort of web design than coding.

Comment: I am learning on web design with SPS. Don't want to mess with master page layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - its not a simple process and can be downright frustrating at times. Think an overloaded plate of spaghetti, move a piece at one side and something at the other falls on the table.

[SharePoint Branding is the search term you're looking for and Heather Solomon](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/brandsppart1.aspx)'s blog is the place to start.

You will also find a lot of companies that can do this for you if you have a budget.